# How to solve error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining fatal: early EOF

Tags: curl, rpc, eof, disconnect, cloning

am trying to clone dhis2 source from a folked repository. am facing the error below

```
Cloning into 'dhis2-android-capture-app'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 169495, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3111/3111), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1344/1344), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
error: 4920 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

what is wrong here, and whats the solution? Have anyone ever successfully folked and cloned the repo here? Which way did you use?

i tried starting the process over and over again because others suggested it could be a network issue. But it did not work. It just showed at some point that i am remaining with few files to complete but still failed eventually. THen show a lot of files remaining on some attempts